# Could not find a part of the path C# asp.net when I generated user session folder in particular directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string UserFolder = Session["Username"].ToString();

if (!Directory.Exists("~/MisReports/EmailAttachment/"+UserFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("~/MisReports/EmailAttachment/"+UserFolder);
}

filePathE = Server.MapPath("~/MisReports/EmailAttachment/" + UserFolder + "/");
filePathE = filePathE + a + ".pdf";

bool isExist = File.Exists(filePathE);

if (isExist)
{
    File.Delete(filePathE);
}

report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, filePathE);
```

I get the error

> Could not find a part of the path
>   if (!Directory.Exists("~/MisReports/EmailAttachment/"+UserFolder))
>   {
>       Directory.CreateDirectory("~/MisReports/EmailAttachment/"+UserFolder);
>   }

in this area code does not enter if check although that the folder has not been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` is probably not evaluated if you are running on Windows. Windows is not Unix. Read up on [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.Path.Combine%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework), [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN. You should build a path with code like

```
string directoryName = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MisReports/EmailAttachment", UserFolder);
```

Comment: Although, for completeness, I should have replaced the / with \ in the constant.

Comment: When i wrote this programming and debug all seems fine folder created all done prefectly but then i deleted session folder and then again debug could not find path occursss :(

Comment: OK, so, generate the path in a string variable. Stop the program in the debugger after setting the variable but before executing the `if`. Look at the path variable and the file system and see if you can spot anything wrong. Execute the `CreateDirectory` method and examine the exception. Detailed exception causes are on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx